# Find similar records

Tags: powershell, qlikview

I have a database of about 800,000 ID numbers (11 or 13 digits each).

Then I have a list of a few thousand ID numbers that was used as a reference but they do not match to an ID number on the database - mostly due to a finger error by the customer. This usually means one digit can be left out or added or incorrect.

I am looking to do a match based on "similar" Id numbers - what would be the best way to go about that?

I am fairly proficient at PowerShell and QLikView, but not sure which to use. Excel is out due to the number of records.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite well-known with data warehousing. Some data quality solutions exist to find out such mistakes, but no tool can figure out every single mistake.

Are you certain that all the IDs that *look* correct *are* actually correct? That is, can you tell that all the matches are good instead of accidentally providing a match? Consider a case in which a typo or several typos do create a valid but incorrect ID.

The second part for non-matches can be resolved to some degree with [approximate string matches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). That is, instead of thinking the ID as values around tera, think about string of 11 or 13 characters long. By calculating the [Levenshtein distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), you might be able to figure out at least some of the typos.

Even with fuzzy search, I'm afraid you can't repair all the broken ID codes, unless the code has some kind of built-in checksum or the digits form groups. That is, digits 1-3 identify something, 4-7 something else and so on. By looking for a ID that has nonsensical subgroups, you might be able to figure out which subgroup has a mistake.